# Rails Devise: Should I use current_user or stick to User.find(params[:user_id])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I wanted to know when using Devise for my User model is there any difference in using `@user = current_user.id` vs `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` in my controllers and views(only current_user). What would be considered the "better" way.

Example:

```
  def index
    current_user
  end
```

or

```
  def index
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  end
```

or

```
 def index
   @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
@user = User.find(current_user.id)
```

makes no sense, since, as you wrote above, you can use:

```
@user = current_user
```

However, `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` can be useful in some cases where you passe a `user_id` parameter (for example in a `link_to` or in a `request`.

Note that the params will not contain the `user_id` if you don't pass it manually. However, `current_user` will always be accessible

Comment: Just to follow up, If i'm using Devise, its okay to use `current_user` basically anywhere I want to? I know in the controller is where it is usually used when I see examples, but using it in views as much as I want is okay as well? Like if `current_user` is available to me why would I even want to use an `@user` instance variable, id just rather use `current_user` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Devise creates current user as a session variable meaning you can use it in any view or controller.

How ever if user is not signed in you will get an error so as an example here are sign in / sign out buttons surrounded by an if statement to check whether current user is specified

```
<% if user_signed_in? %> 
//here we can use current_user for what ever you wish
    <a href="/users/sign_out" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</a>
    <a href="/users/edit/" class="btn btn-default">Edit Your profile</a>

    <% else %>
  // here we cant use current_user as it is not specified


    <a href="/users/sign_in" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</a>
    <a href="/users/sign_up" class="btn btn-warning">Sign up</a>
    <% end %>
```